# How to compare to dict ignoring some fields in Python?

Tags: python

For Example:

I'm checking to see if my input has the same attributes and the same values like the one below except for the fbtrace_id field (which can be any value).

```
{"error":{ 
                       "code":101, 
                       "message":"Invalid Client ID", 
                       "type":"OAuthException", 
                       "fbtrace_id":"SOMEIDHERE"}}
```

So If my input was the structure below, this would be seen as equivalent to the above.

```
{"error":{ 
                       "code":101, 
                       "message":"Invalid Client ID", 
                       "type":"OAuthException", 
                       "fbtrace_id":"CHEESEBURGERS"}}
```

However, if my input was the structure below, this would *not* be "equivalent" as above.

```
{"error":{ 
                       "code":101, 
                       "message":"CheeseBurger", 
                       "type":"OAuthException", 
                       "fbtrace_id":"puppy"}}
```

Comment: So which fields exactly do you want to ignore?

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  For each dict, you make a new structure from the old one *without* the field you want to ignore; then compare the two.

Comment: @LutzHorn I want to ignore fb_trace_id

Comment: I tried creating a variable expected = [{"error":{ 
                       "code":101, 
                       "message":"CheeseBurger", 
                       "type":"OAuthException"}}]                                                          Then I did self.assertIn(expected, input) and I got an error @Prune

Comment: Your assertion failure is correct: `expected` is not an element of `input`; that's the wrong comparison.  You need to strip them both down and check for equality -- or just follow the examples in the linked duplicate.